# MeanShift formula understanding

Tags: image-processing, video-tracking, mean-shift, back-projection

I'm implementing MeanShift algorithm for object tracking, using ideas from here: http://www.cse.psu.edu/~rtc12/CSE598C/meanShiftColor.pdf

Now I have backprojection image for consequent frame. Each pixel in such image marks the probability of belonging to tracked object:[image]

MeanShift formula in aforementioned source looks so:
[image]

w(x<sub>i</sub>) = pixel in backprojection image. 
x = current center pixel.

I don't understand what is `spatial kernel`. 
Assuming it can be 2D Gaussian kernel of size say 5x5, K(x<sub>i</sub>-x)*w(x<sub>i</sub>) can be replaced by pixel of pre-blurred image.

My code look so:

```
    fvect2 findMeanShift(const PlainImage<uint8>& weights_smoothed, fvect2 old_center, DebugOutput& debug)
    {
        //LOGE("first center: %.2f %.2f", old_center.x, old_center.y);

        const int w=weights_smoothed.getWidth(), h=weights_smoothed.getHeight();

        int iter_count = 0;
        fvect2 total_shift(0.0,0.0);

        while(iter_count++ < 20)
        {
            fvect2 fTop(0,0);
            float fBottom=0.0;
            for(int y=0;y<h;++y)
                for(int x=0;x<w;++x)
                {
                    fvect2 cur_center(x, y);
                    float mult = weights_smoothed.at(x, y)[0]/255.0;
                    fBottom += mult;
                    fTop += (cur_center-old_center) * mult;
                }
            fvect2 mean_shift = fTop/fBottom;
            //printf("mean_shift: %.2f %.2f", mean_shift.x, mean_shift.y);

            debug.addArrow(old_center, old_center+mean_shift);

            old_center += mean_shift;
            //printf("old_center: %.2f %.2f", old_center.x, old_center.y);

            total_shift += mean_shift;

            if(mean_shift.lengthF()<0.1)
                break;
        }

        return total_shift;
    }
```

So I just iterate by smoothed backprojection image, and for each pixel:
 add its value to denominator 
 add its value multiplied by shift from current center  to denumerator.

It converges at second iteration, but shift is wrong, and I don't know how to debug it. Probably the problem in formula implementation.
[image]

Please explain me in human language what the spatial kernel is and how to apply it to weight image. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I've understood. Spatial mask is search window. Backprojection doesn't need to be blurred. Applying to entire image, `1`'s are inside search window and `0`'s are outside. On the page 2 of [this](http://ai2-s2-pdfs.s3.amazonaws.com/03e5/eaa9ff7dd027eea70b8789837b2080ab786c.pdf) is simpler explanation.

If to search far from tracked object, results are bad. So the wrong shift point in the question *probably is the mass center of entire image*.

Now my func looks so:

```
    fvect2 findMeanShift(const PlainImage<uint8>& weights, const ImageRect& spatial_roi, fvect2 old_center, DebugOutput& debug)
    {
        const int w=weights.getWidth(), h=weights.getHeight();

        int iter_count = 0;
        fvect2 total_shift(0.0,0.0);

        while(iter_count++ < 20)
        {
            fvect2 fTop(0,0);
            float fBottom=0.0;

            for(int y=std::max(spatial_roi.m_y, 0);y<std::min(h, spatial_roi.m_y+spatial_roi.m_height);++y)
                for(int x=std::max(spatial_roi.m_x, 0);x<std::min(w, spatial_roi.m_x+spatial_roi.m_width);++x)
                {
                    assert(y>=0 && x>=0 && y<h && x<w);

                    fvect2 cur_center(x, y);
                    float mult = weights.at(x, y)[0]/255.0;
                    fBottom += mult;
                    fTop += (cur_center-old_center) * mult;
                }
            fvect2 mean_shift = fTop/fBottom;
            //LOGE("mean_shift: %.2f %.2f", mean_shift.x, mean_shift.y);

            debug.addArrow(old_center, old_center+mean_shift);

            old_center += mean_shift;
            //LOGE("old_center: %.2f %.2f", old_center.x, old_center.y);

            total_shift += mean_shift;

            if(mean_shift.lengthF()<0.1)
                break;
        }

        return total_shift;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

(xi-x) is the distance from centroid to the feature point. If you are using Gaussian kernel, compute 1/sqrt(2pi)*exp(-0.5(xi-x)**2) which is spatial the weight.The tip of this kernel is at the centroid.